# Match comparator unexpected result

Tags: powershell

I'm using -Match to filter some data with e-mail addresses but I get unexpected results.

```
Get-ChildItem $AccountKey -Rec -EA SilentlyContinue| ForEach-Object {
$CurrentKey = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath)
If ($CurrentKey -Match "Account Name") {
    If ($CurrentKey -Match [regex]::Escape('@g')) {
        Write-Host "Match:" $CurrentKey."Account Name"
        }
    }
}

Output:
Match: Outlook Address Book
Match: xx@gx.xy
Match: xxx@gx.xy
Match: xxxx@gx.xy
Match: xxxxx@gx.xy
```

So it correctly finds the e-mail addresses it's supposed to but how on earth does "Outlook Address Book" match with "@g" ?

Using just $CurrentKey -Match "@g" produces the same result.

Thanks!

**SOLVED:**

I accidentally used $CurrentKey in the second If statement, instead of using $CurrentKey."Account Name" which would be correct - Oops! Sorry for buggin' you guys.

Comment: I cannot replicate this. `'Outlook Address Book' -match [regex]::escape(@g)` throws a parse error for me.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[regex]::Escape("@g")`? (with quotes)

Comment: Sorry, I failed to put ' ' around @g when removing any sensitive/identifying content from the example.

Comment: OK, but with this change I cannot reproduce your result. I just get a `False` when I run `'Outlook Address Book' -match [regex]::escape('@g')`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either.

Comment: So it sounds like your example is not actually representative. Please take the time to edit your question and provide an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Stupidity beyond belief here. Problem was that in the second If statement I've accidentally used $CurrentKey instead of $CurrentKey."Account Name"